# Exceptions C++ in vector

Tags: c++, exception

> ```
> #include <vector>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <map>
> #include <string>
> using namespace std;
> vector<char> prime;
> char a='t';
> int number;
> int sqrt_of_n;
> int main(){
>   try{
>       cin >> number;
>       sqrt_of_n = round(sqrt(number));
>       for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) prime.push_back(a);//заполнение массива
>       for (int i = 2; i < sqrt_of_n; i++)
>       {
>           for (int j = 3; j < number; j++)
>           {
>               if ((j%i == 0) && (j!=i)) prime[j] = 'f';
>           }
>       }
>       for (int i = 0; i <= prime.size(); i++)
>       if (prime[i] == 't') cout << i << endl;
>       system("pause");
>   }
>   catch (exception &e){ cout << "Isnt good" << e.what() << endl; }
> }
> ```

Some problems with catching exceptions. I want to catch a out_of_range error in vector, but it didnt work.Thanks

Comment: Please, in the future read the documentation before using something.

Comment: -1: You just needed to read some documentation about [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Its just in a The C++ Programming Language by Stroustrup

Comment: Try is bad for program? Why?

Comment: @H2CO3 LOL. Do you think thsts a good / constructive comment? Don't get me wrong, sometimes I think that when reading newbbies questions too, but....

Comment: @Manu343726 At least it helps keeping the sanity of the C++ community :P

Comment: @H2CO3 good point ;) The C++ comunity is too polluted with Javers and Cers thinking about C++ as a "native and fast version of java with exactly the same syntax and ways to work" or "look, its just C, but with classes. Happy OOP!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator[]` doesn't throw exceptions for out-of-bounds accesses (or for anything else) - use `at` instead, it provides checked index functionality.